# Azure data bricks performance enhance

Tags: performance, optimization, pyspark, databricks

I have queries running on spark cluster. But its taking long time. How can I improve performance?

1. Increase cluster size?

   or
2. changes in configuration like shuffling memory or cache increase

Comment: Did you check the DAG/Summary metrics of the job?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can look at joins in Databricks DAG to investigate what kind of Spark Join Strategies queries are using. E.g. when you have tables small enough to process it on one node, and that is not outer join, you can use Broadcast Hash Join which is the fastest one. You can find more e.g. here:
https://towardsdatascience.com/strategies-of-spark-join-c0e7b4572bcf

Comment: In DAG,how to do I investigate? I am new to this,could you pls elaborate

Comment: Also,I dont have only join operation-static dataframe with dataframe(from structured streaming)